# Bootstrap carousel - need a negative selector

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, carousel

I've got a carousel that contains 3 videos.  As the carousel flips through the 3 videos, the user can play the active video by clicking on it.  When the carousel flips to the next video, the user needs to be able to click new active video while pausing the "inactive" videos.  I know how to select for the active video but how do I select for the videos that are not active?

Here's the jquery:

```
$('div.carousel-inner div.active').click(function(){
  $('div.carousel-inner div.active video').get(0).play()
  $('div.carousel-inner not([div.active)]').get(0).stop()
}
```

Here's the bootstrap carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Video 1</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Video 2</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Video 3</li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"><video>VIDEO1.MOV<video></div>
    <div class="item"><video>VIDEO2.MOV</video></div>
    <div class="item"><video>VIDEO3.MOV</video></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could optimize like this:

```
$('div.carousel-inner div.active').click(function(){
  $(this).get(0).play();
  $(this).siblings().not('.active').get(0).stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want:

```
$('div.carousel-inner .item:not(.active)').get(0).stop()
```